# Using the <option> tag how would I get the user to type something but send the server something else

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete

I have a datalist like so:

```
<datalist id="staff">
    <option value="1">Bilbo</option>
    <option value="2">Picard</option>
</datalist>
```

and a form like this:

```
<label>Person<input name="staff" type="text" list="staff" placeholder="Anne Example"></label>
```

I am using the foundation framework with JQuery.

I need a way so the user can start typing "Picard" and it will autocomplete Picard for them but when the form is actually submitted - it will submit the value 2.
Also the field should be locked so you must choose something from the list so it can't be "Billy" only "Bilbo" or "picard".

Answer (score 0):

**data list** can be used for auto complete but can not be used to for validation.
So i recommend you to use **jQuery UI** for auto-complete with input with validation.

**html**

```
 <form onsubmit="return submitForm();">
    <input id="tags"required="">
    <button onclick="submitForm();">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

**Javascript**

```
    var hint = [
      "Bilbo",
      "Picard",
    ];

  $(function() {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: hint
    });
  });

  function submitForm()
  {
    if($.inArray( $('#tags').val() , hint )==-1)
   {
     //Some Error
    return false;
    }

  else if($('#tags').val()!="")
  {
    $('#tags').val($.inArray( $('#tags').val() , hint )+1); 
    return true;
  }
  }
```

here is [demo](http://shubhampatel.xyz/demo.html)